# Instalación Visual Studio 2015

Tags: visual-studio-2015

Tuve que reinstalar mi notebooke, cuando quiero instalar VS 2015 en win 10 Pro, me dice El Paquete de Configuración está dañado o no existe.
Ya desinstale C++ redistribuible x64 y x86 y los volví a instalar pero sigue igual.
Alguien podría ayudarme.
Gracias

Answer (score 0):

Tuve el mismo problema con la instalación de VS 2015 Community.

En mi caso, la solución fue:
Descargar el **instalador sin conexión a internet** (ISO), montar la imagen y ejecutar `vs_community.exe` con derechos de administrador.